# How to Override OData query in MVC API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata

I'm trying to override the OData queries..

I want to upgrade my application.

the **OLD** application get the User object like this:

`http://localhost:12345/api/users/?$filter=userName eq 'test'`

The **NEW** application will get the User object like this:

`http://localhost:12345/api/users/?userName=test`

I want to support the Old application, and to override the OData query `?$filter=...`

With Overriding I can use the new method and return the right User object.

Is there a way to Override the OData query?

P.S: I need to keep the $top & $orderby OData queries untouched...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF DS doesn´t provide a way to do that. However IIS can help you.

The idea is rewrite the url changing it for that that you need using the URL Rewrite module. For example, in you case you should specify that when IIS receives a request containing *userName* it rewrite it to use *$filter* instead.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Compatibility with older versions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^api/users/?$userName eq (.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:12345/api/users/?$filter={R:2}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Of course I didn´t test it in your application but that´s how we are doing it in our project to keep versions compatibility.

Your should read more about it because there are lots of thing you can do with that IIS module.